# Preserving partial property values between EF contexts

Tags: entity-framework

If I create a model using EF, then extend it by creating another partial class how can I preserve the extended property values between EF contexts? I.e.

I have a Stuff entity that maps to a database table. I extend it by creating a partial class:

```
public partial class Stuff
{
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
}
```

Then set this value and recall in different contexts:

```
        Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
        using (var ctx = new EFPrototypeEntities())
        {
            string someData = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            Stuff newStuff = new Stuff
                {
                    Id = id,
                    SomeDate = DateTime.Now,
                    SomeData = someData,
                    SomeInt = 100
                };
            Console.WriteLine("Added stuff data :" + someData + " with int " + newStuff.SomeInt);
            ctx.AddToStuffs(newStuff);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var ctx = new EFPrototypeEntities())
        {
            Stuff stuff = ctx.Stuffs.First<Stuff>(s => s.Id == id);
            Console.WriteLine("Got stuff with data : " + stuff.SomeData + " and int " + stuff.SomeInt);
        }
```

SomeInt returns 0 in the second context. It returns 100 if I wrap it all in just one context.

Answer (score 0):

you must understand about the Entity Framework context mechanism. Different context uses different memory storage.

When you get data from second context, it gets data directly from database, so the data from the first one can not pass into the second one.

There are some work around solutions for your requirement depends on your code structure:

1. if 2 contexts can be accessed in the same function, just detach object from the 1st context and attach it into the 2nd
2. if 2 contexts are accessed in 2 different functions/calls so you can use a single context for the whole application. You can implement it by using IOC (inversion of control). Some common methods are IOC, Autofac, Microsoft Unity...

Comment: If I use a single context, i.e. in a singleton, does that mean all calls to read and write from the context need to be wrapped in a lock to ensure thread-safety?